# auto-mount USBDrives (vfat) for users other than pi

Tags: usb, mount, user

When a USB drive (vfat) is connected, the system automatically mounts it on **/media/pi/DriveName** with permissions set for user pi. Thus each time I need to change something in the drive, I need sudo from other users.

How can I automatically mount drives at say **/media/userABC/DriveName** with permissions set for user userABC.

*Also, I don't want to mount drives using fstab as all the drives irrsepective of their UUID should mount at **/media/userABC/DriveName***

In nutshell, **need to auto-mount USB drives at /media/userABC/DriveName instead of /media/pi/DriveName with permissions (rw) set for userABC without specifying drive's UUID**

Comment: I'd suggest using systemd over fstab as I already described here: [Is there a way to get a usb external drive automounted on connect and boot?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36743/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-usb-external-drive-automounted-on-connect-and-boot/70451#70451)

Answer (score 0):

Add an `fstab` entry which gives the appropriate permissions.

See `man fstab` for detail.

In general it is better to mount shared devices in `/mnt` and not use the automount.

You should create the mount point with suitable permissions to allow all users to access. As `vfat` does not support permissions (AFAIK) these should be inherited, but there are support options for other filesystems.

I don't use `vfat`, but the following is an example I use for an `ext4` partition.

```
UUID=2dd6c96e-4655-4a04-a8ca-7a5fd39d09bb       /mnt/PiHDD     ext4    defaults,noatime,noauto  0     0
```

Comment: By doing what you suggested, only the drive with UUID 2dd6c96e-4655-4a04-a8ca-7a5fd39d09bb will be mounted at /mnt/PiHDD. But as I have stated in the question, _I don't want to mount drives using fstab as all the drives irrsepective of their UUID should mount at /media/userABC/DriveName_

Comment: @about99ninjas that was just an example. Since your question was vague it is difficult to be precise. If you want promiscuous mount use the appropriate `/dev`

Comment: Actually nope. I just want raspberry to automount each drive in /media/userABC while automatically creating  mount points (directories) just like it automatically happens when you connect a new drive.

Comment: @about99ninjas How is the system to determine what the value of 'userABC' or what the ownership should be when the drive is plugged in?  Don't forget that Linux is a multi-user system : so you can't just say 'the logged in user' because there could be more than one logged in user